# Why am I seeing "An error occurred while trying to run the script." in the UI Automation instrument?

Tags: ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

When I try to run a UI Automation script on iOS 5 devices I am getting the following error:

"An error occurred while trying to run the script."

[image]

The same script is running perfectly in the simulator or on an iOS 4.3.3 device.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

This should fix this issue:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: Worked for me too, after I downloaded an ran, an ahem, more up-to-date version of xcode, then when back to old version.

Answer (score 6):

On devices you should explicity allow to run UI Automation scripts.

- Go to `Settings -> Developer`
- Switch `Enable UI Automation` to **on**

After turning the option on, the error went away and everything worked as expected.

[image: Developer Settings - enable UI Automation]

Answer (score 0):

I would try closing xcode and starting the automation script without xcode running. I had an issue where the process was attached to xcode, when I attempted to run from instruments, xcode got stuck on a breakpoint/crash and I couldn't proceed.

The solution I'm proposing is run Instruments independent of xcode.

Comment: i am getting the same error but no success yet. i have tried all possible hit & trial method but nothing worked yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are having more than one Xcode in your machine either delete others or 
Just follow these steps

1 Open Xcode and go to its preferences.
2 Then open Location tab
3 In command line tools select the Xcode version that you are using . it might be possible that this entry is wrong