# iOS 6 UIAutomation - "an error occured while trying to run the script"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, instruments, ui-automation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I seeing “An error occurred while trying to run the script.” in the UI Automation instrument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906375/why-am-i-seeing-an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-run-the-script-in-the-ui-au)

I'm completely stuck. Every time I try to start UIAutomation tool I'm getting the error:
[image]

I tied to follow [this tutorial](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation)

Any help is appriciated!
Added: the iOS deployment target set to: 4.0
Tried to start on iPhone Simulator 5.0, 5.1, 6.0

Comment: Hi stas, I am facing same problem. If you got the answer please post it.

Comment: I encountered exactly the same issue, with Xcode 5.0.1. for both iOS 6 and 7 simulators. The issue reported in the link of possible duplicate is a little different, where the failure cases are IOS 5 Devices, and the solution suggested there by user1751511 doesn't help my situation either.